# Why do i get only a part of the output in expect_out(buffer) when using -d option for match_max?

Tags: buffer, expect

I was having a lot of troble when i was executing a command remotely and i was getting only
about 70 percent of the output in expect_out(buffer) after some time i removed the `-d` option from match_max and i got the complete output with just

```
match_max 100000.
```

can i get some information of this buffer size related problem and solution.

how do we detrmine this buffer size,is it in kilobytes etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `match_max -d` would reset the buffer size to the default 2000 which may be not enough for you. Note that `match_max -d 100000` is the same as `match_max -d` as 100000 would be ignored here.
- `match_max` without any options will return the current buffer size.

The important thing about the buffer is that the old data in it will be thrown away when the buffer is full and new data are coming in.